# can users bypass restrictions to certain routes or pages in a vue.js application since all the code is rendered on the client side?

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, single-page-application

when building single page app with, for example, firebase, are the api keys used, not visible to the user since all the code is rendered on the client side? And also,since user is restricted to which routes or pages they can visit depending on the conditions set in the code, is it not possible for them to bypass or change the code since everything is on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is correct that the code is client-side in an SPA, restrictions for accessing pages can still be set in place.

VueJS exposes several lifecycle hooks even before elements have been added to the DOM. In this space, you can make a network request to an authentication service. In your request, you would send a token (rf: [jwt](https://jwt.io)).

`await` the response and you can redirect users to the login page, or continue with the component mount.

Comment: i looked into the lifecycle hooks you mentioned and i have seen it's possible to build a secure single page app, making use of the lcycle hoks.there is something that's still bothering me, there is this code i saw, they had 4 <router-link> in the header component, then in the router index.js, they had router.beforeEach, checking if user is logged in. So if the header component is importing the router (index.js) file then when it's created the elements and the javascript associated with the header component are then added to the Dom?.then that means the js in the router js is now exposed right?

Comment: @user11762244 If the header component is importing javascript code (for example, from router/index.js), then yes, when the header is added to DOM, router/index.js code will be included. Any person loading this page will be able to view the source, and in that sense it will be "exposed". Minifcation and obfuscation is not foolproof, so if there are sensitive data you need to access from within components, look into environment variables, when you define in a .env file